# What is the point in returning a value as const

Tags: c++

What is the point in returning a value as const?

```
const int getNum () {return 5}
```

And why can you return a variable that is not specified as const and also assign the returned value to a non-const variable? 
You can do this:

```
const int getNum ()
{
int z = 222;
return z; //hmm shouldn't z be specified as const in order for this to be valid?
}
```

and you assign it to a non-const variable:

```
int q = getNum();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually not sure whether that const has an effect

Comment: @Paul It doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Apparently not and I've read from a dupe that some compilers might even emit a warning stating that in your code example const has no effect..